# Store Query String Data Into Variable For Use In Conditional

Tags: javascript, variables

I've got the first part but can't get the rest.

I "captured" the query string values. Now I need to store those values to variables, and then use said variables to call functions via a conditional.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frankDraws/94yoxctn/19/).

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="redBlue" class="welcome">
        <h2>Which Pill Will You Choose?</h2>
        <div class="buttonWrapper">
            <a href="#?choice=truth" class="button medium queryString">Red</a>
        <a href="#?choice=ignorance" class="button medium queryString">Blue</a>
        </div> <!-- /end buttonWrapper -->
    </div> <!-- /end welcome -->
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div> <!-- /end container -->
```

JS

```
$(".queryString").click(function() {
    var query_string = this.href.substring(this.href.indexOf("=") + 1);
    // alert(query_string);
});

var red = query_string.valueOf("truth");
var blue = query_string.valueOf("ignorance");

if (query_string) {

    // Click red, then call truth() function

} 
else {

    // Click blue, then call ignorance() function

}

// Below are placeholders for the truth() and ignorance() functions.
function truth() { 
    // This function lives in an external .js file
}

function ignorance() {
   // This function lives in an external .js file 
}
```

I've tried: `val()`, `value()`, `valueOf()`, `var red = query_string === "truth";`, and several other ways that I can't remember because I'm fried.

I'm assuming the variables captured change every time the buttons are pressed. Is that right?

I need to capture "truth" or "ignorance" on click, pass those values to variables, use them in a conditional, that will run functions.

Let me try to illustrate the logic:

```
onClick get query string value
var red = query string value == "red"
var blue = query string value == "blue"

if (query string) {
     ...value equals red
     run function truth()
}
else {
     ...value equals blue
     run function ignorance()
}
```

The functions being called live in an external JS file. Those functions make REST API calls to SharePoint and build data tables based on list items (just FYI).

I'd like to keep it as simple as possible. Notice that the query string values were captured without RegEx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do to compare a string to some other string is use `==` or `===`. You need to do that work *inside* the "click" handler; your code as written will do what it does before the "click" handler ever runs.

```
$(".queryString").click(function() {
    var query_string = this.href.substring(this.href.indexOf("=") + 1);
    if (query_string == "truth")
      truth();
    else if (query_string == "ignorance")
      ignorance();
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. I did compare the strings but I did it outside the click handler. You rock! Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

You should convert String and after compare both values

```js
if (String(query_string) === String("truth"))
      truth();
else if (String(query_string) === String("ignorance"))
     ignorance();
```

Comment: The "query_string" variable is *already* being initialized to a string, and there's certainly no reason to convert a string constant to a string before comparing.